# Filter list  by multiple possible values

Tags: list, filter

I want to filter list by multiple possible values of one specified field, how can i do this in code?
I have following lists: Initiatives, Classes of Initiatives and Departments.[image]

I need to retrieve list of Iniciatives, filtered by Classes, that are filtered by Divisions.. So in fact I have for example 2 classes and want to show iniciatives of these two classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it! [Element In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx) - just what I need)

```
                               <Where>
                                  <In>
                                     <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                        <Values>
                                          <Value Type='Text'>xx</Value>
                                          <Value Type='Text'>yy</Value>
                                          <Value Type='Text'>zz</Value>
                                        </Values>
                                  </In>
                               </Where>
```

Answer (score 1):

Department Name should be a lookup column in the Classes List. The Class Name should be a lookup column in the Intiative List. By doing this , you create the basic foreign key relationship as depicted in the diagram.

The above should give you the basic structure to build customized queries on aggregated results from these lists using Dataview webpart. This will help you get started :-
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-data-view-HA010099144.aspx

Comment: I know about lookups) thank you for the link, i just thought that I can do it somehow by linq or caml query